# Getting Normal Distribution from Combinatorics using Stirling's Formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

In one of my assignments, we have a system of 100 particles with 400 possible locations, with region A having 180 locations. The probability of having N particles in region A was $$\frac {C(179+N,N)*C(319-N,100-N)}{C(499,100)}$$ where C is the choose function. The instructor then claims in a side note that using stirling's formula $ln (n!)=n*(ln$(n)-1), you can turn this into a normal distribution. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the steps go as follows:

- Write $\ln P$ out using Stirling's approximation.
- Find the value of $N$ for which $\ln P$ is maximized.  Call this value $N_0$.
- Expand $\ln P$ in a Taylor series about $N_0$ to second order.  Since (by definition) $\ln P$ is peaked at $N_0$, the first-order term must vanish and you will find that$$ \ln P \approx \alpha - \beta (N - N_0)^2
  $$where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants.
- Exponentiate both sides to obtain $P \approx C e^{-\beta(N-N_0)^2}$.

The details of this derivation, including the values of $\beta$ and $N_0$, are left as an exercise for the reader.  Most of the algebraic pain happens in the third step.